# Visual Studion 2017 SSRS report error

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services

I keep getting this error when trying to preview the report in Visual Studio Community 2017.

[image]

When I ran the report in DebugLocal mode I ended up with this error.

[image]
  But the same report works perfectly on the Report Manager as well as on Report Builder (2016) tool.  Please, can I get some advice on this?

Versions of my tools are

[image]

Comment: Do you have custom code in the report?

Comment: @StevenWhite, sorry what do you mean by customer code.  I made it very simple.  The report has no parameters.  It is just a simple select from a view. Thanks.

Comment: Did you put VB Code in the report properties like this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/add-code-to-a-report-ssrs?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: no @StevenWhite.

Comment: @StevenWhite I don't get this error anymore and it works fine now.  But I don't know how it got fixed! But Thank You for your help! - Bhuvana